# Intel Graphics Driver Issues on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

Everything was working good with graphics drivers until I had to replace the motherboard of my **HP m6 Envy 1214TX** laptop computer.

Upon fresh Windows 8 Pro OS installation, I could see WDDM drivers which were installed by default:

[image]

Next, I downloaded the Intel Graphics and Chipset Drivers from manufacturer's site [here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC-series/5330543/model/5384807#Z7_3054ICK0KGTE30AQO5O3KA30R1).

When I tried to install the Graphics driver I get an error:

[image]

Next I downloaded the drivers from Intel's site recommended by *Intel Driver Detect Utility* but after installing I started to get BSoD errors related Paging fault, Memory Management etc. It's not the RAM since I have checked and tested it twice from BIOS and benchmarking tool. So, BSoD only started to happen after installing the drivers.

After uninstalling them, I used a freeware utility called "DriveTheLife" to find compatible drivers. Surprisingly I was able to install the drivers (which appeared to be outdated from 2013) but Windows 8 OS doesn't seem to detect them:

[image]

What can I further do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Remove all graphiccard drivers you have installed from "Device Manager" and
  "programs and features"
- Try this app "[driverbooster](http://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php)" it's more better for graphic cards drivers.
- Restart your PC

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the intel driver reeboot and try this driver from hp

http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-m6-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/5259226/model/5275636